# Flutter CheckboxListTile not responding to changes with stream builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-build

I am trying to use a `CheckboxListTile` in a stream builder and right now I have it showing up in my listView but when I tap it the value is not changing.

I originally had the `bool inPack = false;` before the widget build and that would respond but every item in the listView toggles at the same time which was not what I wanted. I then moved it into the builder where I now believe it should be but now nothing toggles...

```
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      //widget build for completed call
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
              bool inPack = false;
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Card(
                  child: CheckboxListTile(
                    value: inPack,
                    onChanged: (inPack) {
                      setState(
                        () {
                          if (inPack == true) {
                            inPack = false;
                          } else {
                            inPack = true;
                          }
                        },
                      );
                    },
```

Comment: Can you include the stream

Comment: @YeasinSheikh

db
            .collection('GearLockerItems')
            .where('userId', isEqualTo: userID)
            .orderBy('itemName')
            .snapshots(),

Comment: are you putting this on `stream`? and are you updating data server as well ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh eventually yes. Right Now I am literally just tying to set everything to false and see if I can toggle them individually. Once that works I plan to have it take the initial value from the stream and if changed update to the stream as well.

Comment: Actually stream will get new snapshot on data changes, I could be wrong but If you are certain that snapshot will not change until you update from here,   another thing is calling setState will rebuild the ui and `inPack` is false on every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you define inPack inside stream builder so every time you call setState it define again. Put `bool inPack = false` out of stream builder. you should define it out of build so every time you call setState, it not getting define again.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  bool inPack = false // define it here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return MaterialApp(
        ...
    );
  }
}
```

and if you have list of checkbox you have to provide list of check box value, like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      
      List<bool> checkboxValues = List<bool>.generate(10, (index) => false); 
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, innerState) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Card(
              child: CheckboxListTile(
                  value: checkboxValues[index],
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    innerState(
                 () {
                   checkboxValues[index] = value!;
                },
              );
                  }),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    });
      }
    }
```

and final tip, wrap your list view with StatefulBuilder so every time you call setState, it not update all your expensive widget like stream builder. just remember that if you are using StatefulBuilder, you should use innerState instead of setState to refresh state.

Comment: It still is not toggleing my items when I click them, when it is there.

Comment: would you like take it to chat page so I could see your full code?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247613/flutter-checkboxlisttile-not-responding-to-changes-with-stream-builder

Comment: SO this line salved my issue:

      List<bool> checkboxValues = List<bool>.generate(10, (index) => false); 

I did not have to use set state after realizing to use the onChange to update the value in the db instead of the local variable :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate widget(context) to handle this.

```dart
class PackCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool inPack;
  const PackCheckBox({Key? key, required this.inPack}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PackCheckBox> createState() => _PackCheckBoxState();
}

class _PackCheckBoxState extends State<PackCheckBox> {
  late bool inPack = widget.inPack;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: Card(
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          value: inPack,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(
              () {
                inPack = !inPack;
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And use a stream variable ,instead of directly putting the method inside the stream. Also, when new stream will come data will change.

```dart
body: StreamBuilder<int>(
  stream: stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
    bool inPack = snapshot.data?.isEven ?? false;
    return PackCheckBox(
      inPack: inPack,
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: I got this error when I attempt your code:

The name 'PackCheckBox' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'PackCheckBox'

Comment: You need to use custom widget as I've added on top part widget.